# How can I add paging on GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a problem with a GridView. Even though I enabled AllowPaging I still can't see the page numbers and navigate through pages. The data is brought according to the page size, but the paging details (like the number of the pages do not appear so I can navigate further).

```
<asp:GridView ID="recItemsGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" BorderColor="#f5f5f5"
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="3" OnPageIndexChanging="recItems_OnPageIndexChanging">
```

```
private void BindGridView()
        {
            int pageIndex = recItemsGrid.PageIndex;
            int pageSize = recItemsGrid.PageSize;
            GetItemsFromDataSource(pageIndex, pageSize);            
        }

        protected void GetItemsFromDataSource(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var paging = new ReconciliationItemPagingRequest(pageIndex, pageSize);

            ReconciliationItemPagingResult recItemPagingResult =
                ReconciliationItemService.GetJournalItemDetails(Convert.ToInt32(ParentPage.AssignmentID), paging);

            recItemsGrid.VirtualItemCount = recItemPagingResult.TotalRecordCount;
            recItemsGrid.DataSource = recItemPagingResult.Data;

            if (recItemsGrid.VirtualItemCount == 0)
            {
                lblNoItems.Visible = true;
                recItemsGrid.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lblNoItems.Visible = false;
                recItemsGrid.Visible = true;

                if (recItemsGrid.VirtualItemCount > 1)
                {
                    recItemsGrid.Columns[0].Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    recItemsGrid.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                }
            }

            recItemsGrid.DataSource = recItemPagingResult.Data;
            recItemsGrid.DataBind();            
        } 
        
        protected void recItems_OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            recItemsGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            this.BindGridView();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem with using built-in pager is that it STILL expects the total number of rows.

so, if there is 100 rows, then your data source MUST return 100 rows else the page number and count will be all messed up.

Now, taking a "guess" at your code? You looking to do this the CORRECT way, and ONLY pull from the datbase the actual number of rows.

You don't mention the total row count. However, if the total raw pull of data is say 200 rows, then I would just let that flow though to the built in data pager system.

Remember, the built in data pager system actually cheats. It NEVER limited the data pull for you, but only made a page work "reasonable" well by limting the payload (output) to the web page.

so, the built in pager? Hum, good to a max of about 200 or maybe 300 rows tops. And you "just feed" the data source ALL THE ROWS each time on a re-bind. (that's how this works).

As noted, if you data set is larger then that 200-300 rows, then you probably should just dump the built in pager, and roll your own. That way, you ONLY pull the rows for the given page.

So, either remove your code that attempts to ONLY pull the page of rows from the data source, and ALWAYS feed the gv the full data set - that's how the built in pager works.

The instant you only REALLY pull one page of data rows, then the page count will not work and will be all wrong, since the page count is determined by the size of the data set you pull.

So, say this works:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            width="45%" DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging="True" 
            OnPageIndexChanging="GHotels_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="6"   >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"    />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel Name"    />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="270" />                
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

And code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = 
                @"SELECT * FROM tblHotels 
                  WHERE Description is not null 
                  ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GHotels.DataSource = rstData;
                GHotels.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }


    protected void GHotels_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GHotels.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        LoadData();
    }
```

You note VERY close how in fact the FULL data set is pulled each time.

The result is thus this:

[image]

So, if you going to do REAL data base paging (which the built in pager does not do), then you probably are better off to build your own pager system). It would certainly perform MUCH better then the built in system, which as I pointed out does not actually ever limit the data pulled, but ONLY ever pulls all rows each time, and uses that row count to determine the number of pages to put in the pager. And then pulls the page of rows out of the FULL data set.

It should be not all that difficult to roll your own pager, and the advantage would be fantastic performance, especially if you use SQL server side data paging ability. This would then mean, suggest that you could page any size database, and you would ONLY be pulling one page of data and rows from the database. (sql server 2012 or later does have paging support).

I think using a radio button list would be a good choice for a control to render "x" number of buttons, and that would also thus have automatic "one item" in the control list to be highlighted (for the page number you are on).

You don't mention how many rows you have? But, if less then say 200, then remove the code you have that passes the page number, and just ALWAYS feed the GV the whole data set, and let the pager pull out the one page for you.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. The number of rows is variable, but I think there will definitely be cases where it will exceed 200 rows. I will continue to build my own pager system. Thank you once again!

Comment: Ok, later today, I'll post a custom paging exmaple here. As noted I think up to about a max of 300 rows, the built in pager can be used. While this means for each "page" you hitting database and pulling 300 rows again, your still only say "sending" and "rendering" 20 rows on the web page. The "huge" slow down in the web page is not going to be the database pull of 300 rows (just as fast as 50 rows), but the "size" of the overall web page "payload". I suppose you could say pull 300 rows one time to the client side, and page client side, but I think sending 300 rows to the client side is too big

Comment: so, I still think the built in "pagers" are ok, but they have limiations. I seen some try to send 5000 rows to the pager, and that is far too large. So, this is one of those "how big" or "how far" or "how much". So, my "guess" of about max 300 rows is more of a recommend.  So, if you don't have a custom paging routine that actually ONLY pulls the 20 rows for display, then these pagers are still far preferred as to sending 300 rows client side.  They work great, and are handy, but as noted, they pull full dataset each time on page change, and THEN ONLY send the 20 rows to the browser.